# embedding tumblr blog in html site broken in 2018

Tags: javascript, html, embed, blogs, tumblr

I have a blog embedded in my website using the recommended js code snippet from tumbler:

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://toxictuba.tumblr.com/js'></script>
```

but it doesn't work anymore. The code is there and displays in the page source:

http://www.toxictuba.net/?page=blog

I think this might happen because of the new european cookie policy, what can I do? Do I have to embed tumblr's cookie policy too on my own page?
Or some simple fix to have the blog back up?

edit:
after the first comment I tried all kind of different ways to run the tumblr script but nothing works. How do I get this to work?

```html
   <script type='application/javascript' src='https://toxictuba.tumblr.com/js?start=0&num=10'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='https://toxictuba.tumblr.com/js?start=0&num=10'></script>
   <script type='application/ecmascript' src='https://toxictuba.tumblr.com/js?start=0&num=10'></script>
   <script type='text/ecmascript' src='https://toxictuba.tumblr.com/js?start=0&num=10'></script>
   <script type='application/javascript' src='https://toxictuba.tumblr.com/js'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='https://toxictuba.tumblr.com/js'></script>
   <script src='https://toxictuba.tumblr.com/js'></script>
   <script src='https://toxictuba.tumblr.com/js'></script>
```

Comment: Check the console. There you'll see the problem. Wrong mime type.

Comment: I see the console mentions another .me domain I don't even embed. what is wrong there? How do I fix this mime type error?